# How to place two img next to each other for desktop but only one for mobile

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

For mobile there should only be one image showing, but for desktop there should be two img next to each other. The two images are in one section but separated in their own div.
[Picture of HMTL section here with the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBkF1.png)
How do I show the second image on desktop and still place them next to each other.
I have tried using float but then it cancels the display: block and the second image won't show.
[Picture of my CSS styling using @Media queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCqaN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grid (or flex box) to get the images side by side. If you want some space between the images use grid-gap (leve it out if you don´t want that).
To hide the second image on mobile use display: none and then display: block on desktop.

Here is an example on how you can do this whit grid:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://hddesktopwallpapers.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/goose-mages.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="https://hddesktopwallpapers.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/goose-images.jpg" alt="" class="display-none-mobile"/>
</div>
```

```css
    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 1rem;
    }
    .display-none-mobile {
        display:none;
    }
     @media (min-width: 600px) {
       .container {
       /* if you want one image to take more with you ca set 2fr 1fr or 3fr 2fr */
           grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
       }
       .display-none-mobile {
           display:block;
       }
    }
    /* this is so the images don't take to much width, will be applied to all images */
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Our CSS codes will be as follows.
img css :

```
img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
.image-table {
border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 6px;
table-layout: fixed;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
.image-table img {
border: 10px solid #fff;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
}
#sec-profil .col-md-3{          
    clear: both !important;
}
```

Our HTML codes are as follows.

```
<table  class="image-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<img id="sec-profil"  src="img-link-1" alt="" title="">
</td>
<td>
<img  id="sec-profil"  src="img-link-2" alt="" title="">
</td>
<td>
<img  id="sec-profil"  src="img-link-3" alt="" title="">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do ot. Never use table for styling purposes, table is just for table-data. Use css grid (or felx-box)

Comment: What the gentleman says is true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove floats and apply inline block to the div in your styles, your images will be inline.

```css
.desktop-picture {
  display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: This can work, but if the images are to wide the second image will be under the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `.desktop-picture` is set to `display: none;` by default, then set it to `display: inline;` in the media query.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against using `float`'s. Here is an example using `flex` and `flex-flow` with a media query changing to `flex-flow: row;` to align images side by side.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .parent {
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/#ffd11/blue">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/#ffd11/blue">
</div>
```

Another example w/ `grid`.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  place-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .parent {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/#ffd11/blue">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/#ffd11/blue">
</div>
```